# Configure Google Analytics _TrackEvent so that results appear in basic reports

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have several PDFs available for download on a page, and I have configured them with the onclick="ga.push(etc)" and that all works fine.  However, these events are reported separately in the "Events" menu of GA, and therefore I cannot report on these events by Geography, Demographics, Geo, etc.

Is there a way to specifically configure the options of the _TrackEvent onclick event to have the results appear as if the PDF was an ordinary page?  I've tried setting the second option to 'pageview' but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of sending an event you can send a "[virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#virtual-pageviews)" by passing a custom page page to the pageview call (either because the page in question does not physically exist or, as in your case, it's a document type that cannot execute tracking code by itself). So instead of using event tracking you would fire another pageview call like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/myPDFDOcument.pdf');
```

and the url w[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference)ould appear in the page report. You can also send a document title - if you want to override mutiple default values you pass an object as the third parameter with key=>value pairs:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
'page':'/myPDFDOcument.pdf',
'title': 'My document title'
});
```

See the field reference for more options.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I had seen the 'send' usage but later realized I'm on the new GA code that needs the _gaq.push(['_trackPageview' construction instead of the ga() usage. So you got me to rethink something that wasn't previously working.

Comment: Actually the ga is the new one and _gaq is soon to be deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated, but will it still work or is it going to be pulled?